# How to get all records with the last two dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with dates and some other information, where the dates are not continuous (no weekends). How do I get all records from the last two days/dates (which I don't necessarily know beforehand)?

While

`SELECT datum FROM trackproc ORDER BY datum DESC LIMIT 1;`

gives me the last date, and

`SELECT datum FROM trackproc ORDER BY datum DESC LIMIT 1,1;`

the second last one, which is what I want, this statement

```
SELECT * FROM trackproc 
WHERE datum BETWEEN (SELECT datum FROM trackproc ORDER BY datum DESC LIMIT 1) 
            AND     (SELECT datum FROM trackproc ORDER BY datum DESC LIMIT 1,1) 
ORDER BY datum;
```

returns empty.

How would I write such a statement?

Comment: Can you show your table schema?? What's the datum data type??

Comment: CREATE TABLE `trackproc` (
  `proctype` enum('CPD','Hospital','Outreach','Practice','Travel') DEFAULT 'Practice',
  `surname` text NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `firstname` text NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `fileno` char(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `datum` date NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `duration` int(11) DEFAULT 30,
  PRIMARY KEY (`datum`,`fileno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to find the DISTINCT datum values in your record set and get the last 2. Then get all records that have the same date.

```
SELECT b.*
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT(datum) AS datum
    FROM trackproc
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
    LIMIT 2
) AS a
INNER JOIN trackproc AS b ON a.datum=b.datum;
```

Comment: @E Lisse please accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
SELECT *FROM trackproc WHERE datum BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: Returns empty (the two dates are over a weekend and hence empty). I am not looking for the fixed last two days, I am looking for the last to dates in the table (whatever they are). In the actual database the dates I need are today (2022-11-01) and 2022-11-27 (long weekend).